# How can I test if a block is empty?

Tags: ruby, lambda, block

I have a block of code and I'd like to test if the body is empty without running the code inside of the block. Is that possible?

Comment: try block_given? http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F

Comment: block is given, but could be empty. e.g. {}

Comment: I don't need it myself but a colleague asked me and then I started wondering myself how to do it. I'm sure there are uses for it. Perhaps you allow a user to build his own expressions that you want evaluated or something. (eval some_string)

Comment: I'm afraid that Ruby wasn't created with homoiconicity in mind. :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sourcify` gem adds a `Proc#to_source` method:

```
>> require 'sourcify'
=> true
>> p = Proc.new {}
=> #<Proc:0x000001028490b0@(irb):3>
>> p.to_source
=> "proc { }"
```

Once you have the block as a string it's fairly easy to see if there's noting (or only whitespace) between the curly braces.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: Ruby 2.0+ removed block comparison, so it is no longer possible using only the builtin methods.

Ruby used to compare `Proc`s, but was [not great at it](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4559). For instance you could:

```
def is_trivial_block?(&block)
  block == Proc.new{}
end

is_trivial_block?{} # => true
is_trivial_block?{ 42 } # => false
# but caution:
is_trivial_block?{|foo|} # => false
```

Because of this, it was decided to remove the block comparison, so two blocks are now `==` iff they are the same object.